# php warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php

I have a querystring variable whitelist checker on my website. It checks the given url against permissible/allowed querystring variables (key and value). The first part checks the querystring key against allowed keys - if the key is not allowed (not in the whitelist) it will reject the querystring. the second part checks the "value" part of the querystring key/value to see if the value includes a bad word from a blacklist - if the value is in the blacklist it will reject the querystring.

This seems to work well but I notice from my server logs that the line that converts the querystring value to lowercase causes a PHP warning:

> PHP Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
> given

This is the code:

```
$rejectqstr = "N";

//loop through the querystring, check each querystring KEY against the three whitelist arrays. Any key found which is not in the list will set the reject variable to Y

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value){

    if(in_array($key, $cmsnumparams) || in_array($key, $cmsstrparams) || in_array($key, $cmsboolparams)){

        //do nothing if it found

    } else {

        $rejectqstr = "Y";

    }

    //loop through the blacklist values and check each querystring value against the list

    $value = strtolower($value);

    foreach($cmsblklstparams as $blklist){

        if(strpos($value, $blklist) !== false){

            $rejectqstr = "Y";

        }

    }

}
```

its the line `$value = strtolower($value);` that is logged as a warning in the server logs.

I can't see what is wrong with this. My blacklist array (cmsblklstparams) is all lowercase so I convert the querystring value to lowercase before seeing if it is in the blacklist array.

This warning is not listed all the time in the server log so I guess it could be caused if a user tried to "inject" something in the querystring (changing it from a string to an array)?

Is there a better way of doing this or should I check if $value is an array (if so, reject the querystring) before converting it to lowercase?

I've tried testing the code with normal querystrings and it seems to work ok so I'm not sure what it being added to the querystring to cause this warning in the server logs.

Many thanks.

Comment: FYI you don't need to put each line separately with a backtick for code. You should declare a single coherent code block to get better effect. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've now edited the post with the correct formatting

Comment: `could be caused if a user tried to "inject" something in the querystring`...possibly yes, You could try matching this to entries your webserver logs at the relevant timestamp (which should show what the querystring values were) to see if you can see anything like this. `should I check if $value is an array `...probably yes, it's always a risk.

Comment: there may be `array` in your `$value`, try to check what's in it.

Comment: PHP has already told you what the problem is, but you're debugging in the wrong place. If you're getting an array in a query string when you're expecting a string then you need to be looking at the data that causes the warning or the code that creates it. You haven't posted either of those things so there's little we can do except repeat the obvious.

Comment: you'll find this is because of requests with get params of the form `?whatever[]=x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it could be caused if a user tried to "inject" something in the querystring (changing it from a string to an array)?

I would agree, either intentionally or unintentionally. Take for example the following HTML form:

```html
<form action="my-request.php" method="GET">
  <label for="checkbox-setting1">
    Setting 1
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-setting1" name="setting[]" value="setting1" />
  </label>
  <label for="checkbox-setting2">
    Setting 2
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-setting2" name="setting[]" value="setting2" />
  </label>
  <label for="checkbox-setting3">
    Setting 3
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-setting3" name="setting[]" value="setting3" />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Assume this form is submitted with every checkbox checked, it will make a request using the URL `.../my-request.php?setting[]=setting1&setting[]=setting2&setting[]=setting3`

This is a valid GET request and PHP will interpret the `setting` query string parameter as an array. The way your current code is setup is that it always assumes that the incoming query string parameters will be a String.

It sounds like you want to do a type check to check if the currently iterated query string parameter is an array. If it is and you do not allow for arrays, then do your rejection. If it is and you do allow for arrays, then setup an inner loop:

```php
// do not allow query string parameter values
if (is_array($value))
{
  $rejectqstr = "Y";
}

// or allow them
foreach($cmsblklstparams as $blklist)
{
  if (is_array($value))
  {
    foreach($value as $innerValue)
    {
      if(strpos($innerValue, $blklist) !== false)
      {
        $rejectqstr = "Y";
      }
    }
  }
  else if(strpos($value, $blklist) !== false)
  {
    $rejectqstr = "Y";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Many thanks for this. This is really useful and excellently explained. I've been looking at my server logs and while the php_error_log goes back a few months (and shows the "strtolower() expects parameter 1 " warning I received) the IIS server logs only go back about 10 days (before my host recycles them) and the most recent occurence of this issue was on the 1st Jan. I'll wait until I can see in the IIS logs what querystring is causing the PHP warning and then decide whether to reject or accept the arrays as per your solution. Thanks again.